# How to trigger a popup through an else statement in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, popup

Hi i'm using **MVC3** and i'm in the **C#** environment. I would like to have a popup show when an else statement is satisfied.
the code looks like this:

```
if (validate.Count < 1) {
    db.TutorStudents.Add(tutorStudent);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
} else {
    // need some form of popup message here that does not redirect the user                         
}
```

I've been searching and I found *JQuery* solutions, but they work on a click result right... rather, I want the popup to work when the else statement is reached. Any solution is welcome.

Thank you in advance

Comment: where is your else statement exactly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't show popup on the client side from the server directly.

But you can put some marker value to the `ViewData` or `ViewBag` and pass this value to the script in your view:

in the action

```
        if (validate.Count < 1)
        {
            db.TutorStudents.Add(tutorStudent);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.ShowMessage = true;
            //need some form of popup message here that does not redirect the user                            
        }
```

in the view

```
@if (ViewBag.ShowMessage)
{ 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".message-box").show();
        });
    </script>
    <div class="message-box">Some Message here</div>
}
```

Comment: although in the in statement in the view i think you forgot == true in the @if statement... but it works nice

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
if (validate.Count < 1){
    db.TutorStudents.Add(tutorStudent);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
} else {
    ViewBag.PopUp = true; 
    return View(); // or any logic to show the last-view to user again                          
}
```

and in view:

```
@if(ViewBag.PopUp == true){
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Your message here...");
    </script>
}
```

**UPDATE:** You can't show a popup to user via C# in Web-Apps. Because C# runs at server, and you have to create a client-side code to run on end-users browser. So, you must create a logic via C# to control App and generate HTML (and/or JavaScript, jQuery, CSS) to achieve your purpose.